# How to update a layout in kivy after a modification is made?

Tags: user-interface, kivy

How can I update a layout in kivy after a made modification. For instance, i have a GridScroll, where I am storing buttons. However, I want to update the content after I delete one of the buttons.

I tried with do_layout function, but I think it is not working. I also created a button to close and open automatically my programm. So i do not have to close and open it manually.

Comment: You shouldn't need to do anything. The `Layout` should update automatically. Perhaps you should post a [mcve].

Comment: In my case, I create buttons using for-loop. So, every time I add a new item I need to close the app and open it again in order to have it the new items uploaded.

Comment: Please post a [mcve].